# Logstash Filter geo_point with lat long?

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration

Part of my grok filter (working) grabs the following two fields:

%{NUMBER:XCent} %{NUMBER:YCent}

which are lat, long points.

I'm attempting to add a location pin but keep getting a config failure when I use the --debug flag on my configuration file

All of my configuration works until I get to this section.

```
if [XCent] and [YCent] {
    mutate {
        add_field => {
            "[location][lat]" => "%{XCent}"
            "[location][lon]" => "%{YCent}"
        }
    }
    mutate {
        convert => {
            "[location][lat]" => "float"
            "[location][lon]" => "float"
        }
    }
    mutate {
        convert => {"[location]", "geo_point"}
    }
}
```

My thought was that this is basically what the elastic documentation for logstash 1.4 suggested

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/mapping-geo-point-type.html

Edit: found better way to apply configuration in filter, updated code.

Answer (score 2):

The third mutate filter is invalid. [`convert`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-mutate.html#plugins-filters-mutate-convert) accepts a hash as it's argument. And the valid conversions are integer, float, string, and boolean. You don't need this filter so you can just remove it.

To set the `location` field as a [`geo_point`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/geo-point.html) type you need to modify the Elasticsearch index template you are using for your data.